# are bionic abilities legal for shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, halacha-theory, technology, medicine

Today the world is high in technology; many medical fields are experiencing breakthroughs in artificial limbs and what not.

What are the **legalities** of these in Jewish law?

*For example*, a pace maker is legal to be operated on Saturday because it sustains life, but a mechanically operated artificial left hand does not. Is it still legal to use on Saturdays and why?

Comment: Isn't a pacemaker something that runs continuously without intervention?  That seems different from a mechanically-operated limb quite aside from any *pikuach nefesh* considerations.

Comment: I'm disappointed. I thought this question was going to be about Superman-like super powers.

Comment: the hearing aid isn't piku'ach nefesh and is discussed here http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/journal/sandler-1.htm this site alludes to an article but the link doesn't work http://www.vosizneias.com/47075/2010/01/15/jerusalem-thought-controlled-gadgets-pose-new-halacha-challenges/

Comment: things that are nessisary like pacemakers are for obvious reasons allowed. (pacemakers, breathing machines.)   but things like artificial hands are not needed to survive.

Comment: Ess Kay, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! I hope you'll poke around and find other material here of interest, perhaps inlcuding our 86 other questions about [tag:medicine].

Comment: One precedent to consider is that of the [electric scooter](http://www.zomet.org.il/eng/?CategoryID=248&ArticleID=91&Page=1), which is not used passively like a pacemaker or hearing aid, and is not inherently life-saving like a pacemaker. It may be distinguishable from a prosthetic hand, though, since it's even more "external" to the body, and perhaps due to other particularities of their respective uses.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6797/759

Comment: an electric scooter is a great example, Isaac

Answer (score 2):

The prohibition of using electricity is partially Rabbinic, partially not. (This is not to imply that Rabbinic prohibitions are unimportant).

However, there is a rule that if someone is sick (for certain degrees of illness) then Rabbinic prohibitions are permitted (are relaxed). This is not because they are unimportant but because when they were enacted in the first place, they were enacted with that exception.

This is only a general answer. For the *specific* type of illness and type of electric machine I can not answer - this is something you need to ask a Rabbi about.

Comment: This answer could be improved with sources but I can't right now.

Comment: The question is for (unnessisary to sustain life) mechanical devices such as the scooter, or elevator or bionic arm -- when not needed for an emegrency (you will not die without a scooter or arm )

Comment: @EssKay I know. You may set aside Rabbinic prohibitions even for non-essential things in some cases.