# Can a "brain controlled" prosthetic be used on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, technology, parts-of-the-body, electricity

New prosthetics are controlled by [brain waves](https://futurism.com/mind-controlled-robotic-arm-johnny-matheny) which seem to make the prosthetic an extension of the body in an "organic" way, in that we control all of our own limbs through the same brain waves and impulses. [scientists -- sorry, my understanding is rudimentary -- if I am misrepresenting anything, please let me know]

[This](http://www.torahforum.org/Halachos_of_Superheroes.pdf) bit of Purim Torah (with actual sources) seems to point to the idea that telekinesis (movement of an object using the brain) would be allowed on Shabbat, but the question is about moving something external to the body and one opinion questions if using brain waves is k'lachar Yad. Moving a body part is not exactly the same, as brain impulses are the normal way of moving body parts.

[This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16669/prosthetic-limbs-in-halacha) question asks about prothetic limbs in halacha but doesn't address this aspect of controlling their electronics when the electronics are integrated into the body (I learned that attached body parts are not muktza but I don't know when a limb is or is not "attached" enough to become a halachic body part, unlike a [car](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6797/will-rabbis-allow-brainy-shabbat-driving/12975#12975)).

So would the electronic body part be able to be controlled on Shabbat by the brain of the "wearer"?

Comment: Excellent job finding and distinguishing from related prior posts!

Comment: aren't all natural limbs controlled naturally by "electronics"?

Comment: related: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/journal/sandler-1.htm

Comment: @Loewian Spot on, and so I don’t see what the halachic issue(s) could be.

Comment: @Oliver I think the relevant equivalent might be closer to a cochlear implant. Is a bodily adjunct part of the body making the brain waves the natural way of controlling, or still an external device (as one aspect of the halachic issue).

Comment: @rosends Aah, that question. Have you ever seen anyone prohibit the use of a cochlear implant? (Not sure though what exactly would be “prohibited”; surgically remove every week, not allow the implant to begin with, prohibit non-essential adjustments...?) Secondly, the cochlear’s sound processor is battery powered. Are said prosthetics also?

Comment: @Oliver the cochlear implant is actually a different issue (closer but not identical) because it what "sets it off" and makes it process when it is in YOUR head, is MY speaking, am I forbidden to talk in your presence because it is an electronic device that I am intentionally triggering on Shabbat. The electronic prosthetics surely have some power source. Now that I think of it, this would be an issue even for a regular hearing aid. If you wear it and I speak, am I causing it to process on Shabbat?

Comment: If you’re able to accurately describe how the noise is processed and how the triggering operates you’ll get closer to your answer vis a vis halachic ramifications.

Comment: @Oliver http://www.zomet.org.il/eng/?CategoryID=198&ArticleID=283#a6 items 7 and 8 don't really get me an answer...

Comment: @rosends Well again, I’m not sure what halachic issue is at play with (powered) prosthetic limbs. As technological advances continue to develop [I personally find] it gets harder to identify a halachic issue involved.  So putting the electric element aside, as you’ve seen most (maybe read: all) permit devices such as cochlear implants, you’re left with something akin to the [m. Shab. 6:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Shabbat.6.8?with=all&lang=bi).

Comment: @Oliver my concern is more because of the electronics, and whether the control of them vis-a-vis their electronics is categorically different from using the brain to make any bodily movement that isn't electronic. The cochlear implant website makes some guesses and assumptions (and the squelch issue further muddies it). But again, that implant question is a separate one.

Comment: @rosends I understand your general concern which is why I recommend first describing the (problematic) electronic features; that can be the only way to identify specific halachic issues. It’s fundamental bec. as Loewian points out, natural limbs also depend on natural “electronics” and charged cells.

Comment: מלאכת מחשבת אסרה תורה... ;)

Comment: This guy hacked his prosthetic to play his electronic instrument with his thoughts. https://youtu.be/qSKBtEBRWi4 I'm sure you can see why this can be assur. One can hack his keyboard to his prosthetic and run his business on thoughts. The ability to run a factory in a timer was why Reb Moshe was fairly stringent about them.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I upvoted this when you asked it originally, and I really hope someone has a good sourced answer, but it's hard for me to imagine someone allowing this door to who knows what else to be opened.

Answer (score 1):

There are two schools of thought on electricity in Shabbos.

The Chazon Ish holds that closing a switch is boneh, building, and therefore a forbidden labor on Shabbos.

Rav Auerbach argues that the switch is like opening and closing a door, which the Shulchan Aruch says is not binyan in the simple case, it was made to open and close.

Where all agree, is that cooking with electricity is not permitted.  In other words, the problem is what you do with electricity, and not so much the electricity in and of itself.

All electro-mechanical devices produce heat.  That heat can be the problem, in the case that it might be called bishul (cooking).  Hypothetically speaking:  For a metal, a threshold for bishul can be when the metal becomes soft, and for fire it is when it gives off glowing sparks.   So, it depends on the materials, and the amount of waste heat, and whether it glows or gives out light as a result of the electrical process.

As a practical matter, it becomes a question for a Rov for the individual device.

Answer (score 0):

The Steipler says it is permissible to trap a snake using magic on Shabbos, because you didn't do an action (I assume he is referring to a snake charmer). So the question could be, is controlling an electronic device using brain-waves the same thing, because there is no action, just mind-control, as if it were.

Probably the answer depends on if this becomes the normal way of doing things. Because if it does, it would become a maleches machsheves.

Le'mashal, let's say you killed someone by launching a missile using brain-waves. Lichorah it is obvious if that is what weaponry will develop to, you would be chayav misah.

Comment: It literally already is a maleches machsheves.

Comment: In that case it should be assur to walk down the street if someone has trained a camera on the street and got it to record every time someone walks past?